# How avoid Eclipse load test-class file in to classpath when Java app run?

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

I am using [STS](https://spring.io/tools/sts) to develop a large Spring Boot based application. We have multiple maven projects and a parent project to include them all. Each project has own testing code and config files.

When I run the Spring Boot application in the main entry class. The test-classes folder of the depended projects will be loaded into the app running classpath, that causes some conflict of spring bean definition. I have to config every project removing [src/test/java and src/test/resources] from the 'source folders on build path'.

The whole project structure is like below:

> app-parent
>
> sub-app-1
>
> sub-app-2
>
> sub-app-3
>
> main-app [running from this project]

main-app project has dependencies on the sub-app-1 ~ 3.

Is there any way to let STS (Eclipse) run a Java App excluding the test-classes folder from classpath? I really do want the testing code under source folder but not have them when the App run.

Besides, I tried open the [run configuration], but it can only add more file to the classpath.

[image]

Comment: Right at the bottom of the dialog you show in your screenshot, there's a checkbox called "Exclude test code". When ticked, your test classes should be ommitted from the classpath.

Answer (score 7):

As pointed out by @torsten-crass, verify that `Exclude test code` is ticked in your `Classpath` tab of Run configurations in Eclipse.

Here is the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: somehow all my boot launch configs did have that unchecked. is this not the default or are just my eclipse settings screwed up?

Comment: @elonderin not sure. I started to face this when I recently updated my Eclipse.

Comment: @elonderin: It's not the default, but in my view it _should be_: if I run a program which is neither a JUnit test nor even located in the `src/test/java` folder, I should expect that data from under `target/test-classes` are _inaccessible to the ClassLoader_ - unless explicity stated otherwise. I've been surprised to find that Eclipse behaves differently.