# For running Java main application in Eclipse, how to exclude test-classes in classpath?

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2e

I am running a Spring Boot application (java main function) in the eclipse. It is a maven based project. I think eclipse uses m2e plugin to run it. But every time I run my project, the test-classes folder is added to the classpath in the final command.

[image: 1]]

I have to manually remove the test folder (src/test/java and src/test/resources) from source folder in all sub-projects. But when I right click the project, Maven -> Update Project... , the test folder be added to source folder again automatically. Then the final test-classes folder be added into classpath for the run command.

Comment: How are you executing it from Eclipse?

Comment: As I said, my app is a Spring Boot Application, I just right click the class file which has the main function, then select Run As -> Java Application

Comment: Ah...Ok. What about running/testing from command line via `mvn spring-boot:run`....

Comment: @Chris What do you mean by sub-projects? Are they Maven modules? How are they wired together? Or more specifically how `nqsky-meap-open` referred from `api-server`? Test-classes are not added by Eclipse to the runtime-classpath (usually), so there might be some configuration problem there.

Comment: @helospark Sub-projects means sub-module of Maven. We have a parent module for all the projects. And then there is a main module, in its pom.xml file, all other sub-modules are declared as dependencies. The main module test-classes are not included in the runtime classpath, but the sub-modules did.

Comment: any update on this? or eclipse doesn't have any way to exclude test folder?

Comment: @NehaChoudhary A similar question is posted and the answer seems to be relevant here as well - https://stackoverflow.com/a/62554182/979772

Answer (score 0):

In current Eclipse version there is a checkbox "Exclude test code" in Dependencies tab to exclude src/test sources.